# Multiassignment in VB like in C-Style languages

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, variable-assignment, c#-to-vb.net

Is there a way to perform this in VB.NET like in the C-Style languages:

```
struct Thickness
{
    double _Left;
    double _Right;
    double _Top;
    double _Bottom;

    public Thickness(double uniformLength)
    {
        this._Left = this._Right = this._Top = this._Bottom = uniformLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of the multiple assignment versus performing each assignment individually?
Many translator applications will optimize the two to be equal at run-time.

Comment: Yes, there is an advantage. If you want to assign a specific value, say 1.7834 to H(I) and W(J), you have to type 1.7834 only once, effectively treating it as a 1-time constant, whereas typing it twice, it's not obvious that the two constants, although equal, are the same constant. E.g., if H & W are the height and width, it could be a coincidence that the height & width are equal or they might always represent a square.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Expanding on Mark's correct answer

This type of assignment style is not possible in VB.Net.  The C# version of the code works because in C# assignment is an expression which produces a value.  This is why it can be chained in this manner.

In VB.Net assignment is a statement and not an expression.  It produces no value and cannot be changed.  In fact if you write the code "a = b" as an expression it will be treated as a value comparison and not an assignment.

Eric's recent blog post on this subject for C#

- http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/11/chaining-simple-assignments-is-not-so-simple.aspx

At a language level assignment is a statement and not an expression.

Comment: For info, it is a wishlist item to add support for this: http://blogs.msdn.com/lucian/archive/2010/02/12/req7-have-separate-syntax-for-assignment-and-comparison.aspx

Answer (score 9):

As soon as I post this, someone will provide an example of how to do it.  But **I don't think it is possible**. VB.NET treats the single equals in the r-value as a comparison.  For example:

```
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
  i = 5
  j = i = 4
  Debug.Print(j.ToString())
  j = i = 5
  Debug.Print(j.ToString())
```

The above code prints 0 (false) and -1 (true).

Comment: It's not possible. Here's where Lucian, who leads the VB.Net specification, blogs about whether it's worth adding. http://blogs.msdn.com/lucian/archive/2010/02/12/req7-have-separate-syntax-for-assignment-and-comparison.aspx For bonus marks here's Eric Lippert (works on C# compiler) blogging about how confusing it is in C#. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/11/chaining-simple-assignments-is-not-so-simple.aspx