# Chained assignment in VBA

Tags: vba, vb6, excel, programming-languages

Like C/CPP/CSharp/JScript, how can we do chained assignment in VBA? In other words, does VBA have right-associativity of assignment operator?

For example in C-sharp and JavaScript, we can use:

```
var alpha, bravo, charlie;
alpha = bravo = charlie = "hello";
```

Now writing this expression in VBA would have to:

```
Dim alpha, bravo, charlie
alpha = "hello"
bravo = "hello"
charlie = "hello"
```

But we can't use:

```
Dim alpha, bravo, charlie
alpha = bravo = charlie = "hello"
```

VBA doesn't allow to collapse the expressions. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, VBA doesn't have the right-associativity for assignment operator. However, VBA does have the right-associativity or chaining operations for other logical operators. Consider the following expression:

```
alpha = 3
bravo = 5
charlie = 4

alpha = bravo < charlie

MsgBox(alpha) 'would display false

alpha = 3
bravo = 5
charlie = 4

alpha = bravo > charlie < alpha

MsgBox(alpha) 'would display ture .. because (bravo > charlie) is true 
                                      'and true (or 1) less than alpha
```

However, VBA interpreter prioritize the comparison operator over assignment operator, both are represented by `=`. To wit,

```
alpha = bravo = "hello"
MsgBox(alpha) 'would display false, because bravo <> "hello"
```

Thus, you need to use multiple statements explicitly for assignment.

Answer (score 1):

In stead of below assign function I would use

```
Public Sub Assign(ParamArray varsAndValue() As Variant)
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim value As Variant

    If UBound(varsAndValue) < 1 Then
        Err.Raise 999, "Invalid call to «Assign»: Last argument should be the value to set, first upto one but last should be the variables"
    ElseIf UBound(varsAndValue) < 2 Then
        Err.Raise 999, "Why don't you use a normal assignment when you only need to assign one variable?"
    Else
        value = varsAndValue(UBound(varsAndValue))
        For idx = 0 To UBound(varsAndValue) - 1
            varsAndValue(idx) = value
        Next idx
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in the sense you want to do it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312151/multiassignment-in-vb-like-in-c-style-languages) indicates that functionality also doesn't exist in VB.net.

As written, VBA uses the left most = sign to assign the value to alpha and *all* others for comparison purposes.

The only options you have of assigning multiple variables at once is with arrays.

These examples come from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?18225-Initializing-Arrays-with-a-single-statement)

```
Dim myarray As Variant

myarray = Array("Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit")
```

or

```
Dim MyStringArr() As String
MyStringArr = Split("Text1,Text2,Text3", ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it with a function like this:

```
Private Function assign(var As Variant, value As Variant) As Variant
    var = value
    assign = value
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim alpha, bravo, charlie
    Call assign(alpha, assign(bravo, assign(charlie, "hello")))
    Debug.Print alpha, bravo, charlie
End Sub
```

... but it quickly gets ugly.